# How to add customer type filed in magento 2 at frontend registration?

Tags: magento2, frontend, customer-account

While creating the customer from admin, it asks for customer type.

I want to add same drop down option at front end for user creation form (Registration form). Can you please explain how to do it? It is not adding new customer attribute. Enabling default attribute in front end.